# ASP.NET MVC "Editable" ListBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

I am using ASP.NET MVC platform. In my controller I am creating ViewBag that selects i.e. all the names from the database. I have a @Html.listbox in my view and I am using select2() ajax function which is used for suggesting as i type in listbox. In example if i write "Ma" I get listed Maria, Mario, Martin as suggested since I have them in the database. My problem is that I am able just to choose between them, and not add the new name which is not in database. Can you give me any idea or example how I could accomplish that? I would like to use some suggesting as Google has, you type, get suggestions, choose something and then you are able to change it and add it to model.

Here's my code in the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Names, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => Model.Names, null, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Names, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $("#Names").select2({
            placeholder: "Filter names",
            maximumSelectionSize: 1,
        });

    });
</script>
```

And I am doing this in my GET in controller:

```
// GET: Names/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Names= new SelectList(db.Names.Select(n => n.Names));
    return PartialView("_Create");
}
```

**EDIT:**
**I use jquery autocomplete now like this:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("#tags").autocomplete(
            {
                source: '@Url.Action("TagSearch", "Home")'
            });
    })
</script>
```

**And I changed my html.textbox like this:**

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="ui-widget">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Names, null, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @id = "tags" })
                </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Names, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Also I have a function that returns JSON and it works perfectly, the problem is now that when i type in suggestions are behind my partial view (between partial view and Index view) and in a form that I can not choose any of them (something like big label...). Any help on this?

Comment: jQuery [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple) allows you to do this

Comment: That looks like something that can be really useful for me and I am trying to implement it in my code right now. Thanks, and you can post it as an answer so I can accept it when I am done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I ended up changing my script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("#tags").autocomplete(
            {
                source: '@Url.Action("TagSearch", "Home")',

                open: function(){
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('.ui-autocomplete').css('z-index', 99999999999999);
                    }, 0);
                }

            });
        return false;
    })
</script>
```

I had a problem with the z-axis, and this fixed my problem perfectly, after using Autocomplete like Stephen suggested in comment.

Final versions of my view is this:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-6 ui-widget">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Names, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @id = "tags" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Names, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
   </div>
</div>
```